# How to plot with matplotlib in pycharm?

Tags: python, debugging, plot, graph, pycharm

I just need help with debugging what I have. I followed an example from our book as best to my understanding, but I am still having problems! I want to plot the time of sunrise and sunset throughout one year (2022) by importing the data from a file. I was able to figure out the importing stuff correctly (I hope), but when I run this in Pycharm (IDE I am using) I am still getting errors.

Specifically these ones:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sosar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 27, in 
left_axis.plot(date, sunrise, label = "Sunrise")
File "C:\Users\sosar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 1688, in plot
lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\sosar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 311, in **call**
yield from self._plot_args(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\sosar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 504, in _plot_args
raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (365,) and (364,)

I am honestly not good at coding and debugging. This took a long time to figure out, and I am unsure if I did right! But I will post my code below!

ALL HELP IS APPREFCIATED AND THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!!!!

```
import csv
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 with open('sr_ss_clean.csv') as temp_file:
     sunrise = []
     sunset = []
     reader = csv.reader(temp_file)
     next(reader)
     for row in reader:
         sunrise.append(float(row[1]))
         sunset.append(float(row[2]))

start_date = datetime.date(2022, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2022, 12, 31)
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
date = []

while start_date <= end_date:
    date.append(start_date)
    start_date += delta

figure= plt.figure()
left_axis = figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
right_axis = left_axis.twinx()

left_axis.plot(date, sunrise, label = "Sunrise")
left_axis.plot(date, sunset, label = "Sunset")

left_axis.set_xlabel('Date')
left_axis.legend(loc= 'upper left')
right_axis.set_ylabel('Time of Day')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error says the following for `left_axis.plot(date, sunrise, label = "Sunrise")`:

```
x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (365,) and (364,)
```

This means that your list with date is 365 rows long but your list with sunrise is only 364 rows long. This throws an error because your plots 365th x-value cannot find a 365th corresponding y-value.

If you would use:

```
left_axis.plot(date[0:364], sunrise, label = "Sunrise")
```

It would probably work. Here we limit the date onto 364 values.
You are missing a day somewhere in your Sunrise list.

Comment: So, I tried your method, but it still gave me the same error. Would it be possible for me to just graph specific days of the month like the first of the month?

Comment: Are you sure its the same error? Maybe you get an error for sunset now? Anyways to only pot the first 30 dates you could write left_axis.plot(date[0:30], sunrise[0:30], label = "Sunrise")

Comment: Yeah it was the same. I did try your suggestion for the sunset as well and it did work. I finally got a graph, but the issue now is that it labels until 01/2023. I am really unsure of where I went wrong! Would it be possible for me to chart just the first day of each month like 01/01/2022 and so on? Thank you for your help!

Comment: google for python list. your date,sunrise, sunset are lists. and you can chose whatever values you like. You only have to make  that the number of chosen values for date/sunrise/sunset is the same or you get an error again. This means if you want to plot 10 sunseet values then you also have to chose the 10 corresponding date values